# Funny characters in Visual Studio output window

Tags: visual-studio, utf-8

I have written an External Tool that uses `plink.exe` to execute `gcc` on a Linux system and then capture the output back on VS's output window (there is a checkmark in Tools/External Tools/Use Output Window). But Linux outputs with UTF-8 and so I get some garbage. Is there any way to get VS to translate that UTF-8 output to readable output?

For example, Linux is trying to output this:

```
test.c:214: warning: conflicting types for ‘test_zero_read’
```

but it shows up in VS's output window like this:

```
test.c:214: warning: conflicting types for â€˜test_zero_readâ€™
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing the font of the output window can also address the issue of the characters.
In VS go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors ->Show Settings for: Output Window

Answer (score 0):

pipe the output on the linux box via unix2dos before finishing.

Edit: another go:

iconv -f utf8 -t iso89 oldfile > newfile

(from [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/convert-file-from-utf8-to-ascii-encoding-458839/))

Comment: That didn't do it. I think that only removes cr's.